# Itô's lemma and Feynman-Kac theorem for Lévy processes?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I'm facing the problem to try to extend some financial way of reasoning in the case we do not live in the platonic Brownian Motion world. I come from an economic background so I'm stuck on this: the idea is to use, say, an infinitively divisible Lévy process: in that case are my above cited work instrument Itô's lemma and Feynman-Kac theorem applicable?